# Display screen on button click in blackberry eclipse

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I recently started creating an app for blackberry. I want the app to display a screen (Let's say it's called "InfoScreen") but as I said i am still very new to this. What code will I have to use if I want the "InfoScreen" to be show when the button "buttonInfo" is clicked?

Here is some code I used to create the button that is might relevant to this question.

```
    //Create button
    ButtonField buttonInfo = new ButtonField("Information", Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    //Center buttons
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);        
    vfm.add(buttonInfo);
    add(vfm);
```

What code will have to be used for both touch-screen devices and those that use the track-pad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FieldChangeListener infoListener = new FieldChangeListener() {   
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) { 

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new InfoScreen());

       }   
        };   
   buttonInfo.setChangeListener(infoListener);
```